# How to take a collection offline/online?

Tags: mongodb

How would I take a mongo collection "offline" in the sense that the data is NOT deleted, but that the database engine is not aware of that collection.  Is this possible in Mongo?  And if so, how do I bring the collection back "online", in the sense that I can point mongo to the collection on-disk and Mongo will now manage that collection.

Comment: User permissions would be an option. Any prodcution database should be locked down with user access and roles. You cannot really make it *"go away"* without actually removing, but at least you can block write permissions, and even read.

Comment: @BlakesSeven good idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [export](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/program/mongoexport/#bin.mongoexport) a collection, then [drop](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.drop/) it. It wont prevent mongodb to create the collection again though. Also pay extra attention to the part of the docs which describe possible data loss when you [import](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) it back.